# VS2013 Javascript intellisense not working for everything

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Currently my intellisense in visual studio is working for things like $(this).hide etc. But for the code below it is not working when I want to pull op for example the ajax, serverside and columns. When I press ctrl-space I get no options that I could add. I'm unsure what is causing this? Is this not supported or do I need to configure something?

```
$('#example').DataTable(
        {
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'GetUsers',
        columns: [
            { data: 'Id', visible:false,sortable:false},
            { data: 'UserName' },
            { data: 'EmailAddress' }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Try to refresh with Ctrl + Shift + j

Comment: ctrl-shift-j is not doing anything.... Also no feedback from vs.

Comment: Strange, you should see the updating message in the lower left corner...

Comment: I tried it also with changing the DataTable to .animate... Then I also get a get and set als possible hints.

Comment: Take a look at this info, might help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2013/11/07/from-the-mvps-script-references-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: I setted up the _references.js. Also, when I do a $(something) and press a . I get the hints. Just not for the properties that you could set.

Comment: You get intellisense on $(something) because you referenced jQuery I believe, but DataTable is a different plugin isn't it?

Comment: It is a different plugin. I also referenced it. The thing is, when I do for example an $(something(animate({....}); The properties you can set in the location of the .... are also not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio uses commented XML-like markup to build javascript intellisense.

Basically, you add markup of this form (say this code is in `myScript.js`):

```
function myFeature (enable) {
    /// <summary>Summary of the function</summary>
    /// <param name='enable' type='Boolean'>True: RW, False: RO</param>

    [function code here]
}
```

In this example, you can see the parameter `enable` is declared as a boolean, you will get intellisense accordingly.

There are numerous tags you can use: `<summary>`, `<param>`, `<field>`, etc.

**You can find documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb385682.aspx).**

To access this intellisense from another script file, you will need to add a reference as [Dean.DePue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280960/dean-depue) said (`/// <reference path="~/Scripts/myScript.js" />`).

### Now back to your problem

DataTable does not provide in its [script file](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js) markup to describe to visual studio how things work inside of it. Visual Studio is still able to get the functions available, but no additional info is found.

Note that you can also provide this markup in a separate file (often called a vsdoc file). It allows for us to embed minified files but still get the intellisense by using the `// <reference>` that points to the vsdoc file.

---

### To sum it up

DataTable does not provide intellisense info ([and does not have a separate vsdoc file](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9909/is-there-a-vsdoc-for-datatable-so-i-can-get-intellisense-for-visualstudio)), that is why you don't get anything.

As per the `animate` function, the first parameter is declared as `type=Object`, so it can be any object without further detail.